# Understanding the proof of every convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I want to understand why in this proof:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergent_Real_Sequence_is_Bounded

It was taken $\epsilon = 1$. Why was it needed to specify a value for $\epsilon$? Wouldn't the proof be true if I just take the bounds as $K= \max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_N|,|L|+\epsilon\}$?

Comment: Any $\epsilon>0$ works. Of course, the resulting bound at the end depends on which $\epsilon $ you took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only once you make $K$ specific - by specifying $\epsilon$. But you could have taken $\epsilon=42$ instead of $\epsilon=1$, it would not matter for the overall result.

Comment: But is it a valid proof without the specification of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Alnitak You need to provide a specific bound. Without fixing $\epsilon $, all you have is a function (that to each concrete value of $\epsilon $ assigns a $K $). If your question is whether you can just say "Fix $\epsilon>0$" rather than "Take $\epsilon=1/\sqrt\pi $", then yes, of course.